# How to automate this in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need to automate this task in excel:
I have 2 excel workbooks:
One has this kind of information:

```
A               B                 C
1 TABLENAME1    FIELDNAME1
2 TABLENAME1    FIELDNAME2
3 TABLENAME2    FIELDNAME3
4 TABLENAME3    FIELDNAME1
5 TABLENAME3    FIELDNAME2
6 TABLENAME3    FIELDNAME3
```

And the other:

```
A                   B
1 TABLENAME1        FIELDNAME3
2 xxTABLENAME1xx    FIELDNAME4
3 TABLENAME2xxx     FIELDNAME2
4 XXTABLENAME3xx    FIELDNAME1
```

Note: "A" and "B" are just the cell headers.

I must search every tablename with its respective fieldname from the first Workbook in the second Workbook. But there is a problem: Tablenames in the second workbook can be contained inside another bigger string, so something like `LIKE` sql command is needed here.

At the end of the search, results must be put in the C column, this way:

```
A               B                 C
1 TABLENAME1    FIELDNAME1      NO
2 TABLENAME1    FIELDNAME2      NO
3 TABLENAME2    FIELDNAME3      NO
4 TABLENAME3    FIELDNAME1      YES
5 TABLENAME3    FIELDNAME2      NO 
6 TABLENAME3    FIELDNAME3      NO
```

As you can see Tablename3 with fieldname1 is the only row that is found in the second Workbook.

How can I make this using excel formulas or macros?
Please help me, it would save me a lot of time since this task has actually thousands of rows.
EDIT: Search must be not case sensitive.

Comment: `=IFERROR(MATCH("*" & A1 & "*",$G$1:$G$10,0)=MATCH(B1,$H$1:$H$10,0),FALSE)` where (for simplicity) columns G and H on the same sheet represent columns A and B on sheet2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
=IF(
AND(
IFERROR(MATCH("*" & A1 & "*",[Workbook2.xlsx]Sheet!$D$2:$D$16074,0),FALSE)  
,
IFERROR(MATCH(B1,[Workbook2.xlsx]Sheet!$E$2:$E$16074,0),FALSE)    
),"YES","NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

If on Excel 2007 and higher, put this formula in 'Sheet1' cell C2 and copied down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,"*"&A2&"*",Sheet2!B:B,C2)>0,"YES","NO")
```